# unable to start python manager.py runserver

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am creating a sample application using Python V3.6 and Django V2.1, previously I have faced an issue related to MySQL client, so I have fixed that by using "`pip install "mysqlclient==1.3.12`" I help to install the **mysqlclient** successfully but later on when I tried to run my application  I'm getting this following error.

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000003A93C80>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 2
16, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 1
94, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line
227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connec
t
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __
init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 780, in w
riteout_cache
    self._writeout_input_cache(conn)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 764, in _
writeout_input_cache
    (self.session_number,)+line)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was crea
ted in thread id 1776 and this is thread id 10192
```

Setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

If I tried with the default database(sqlite3), it is working fine for but when I try to change that into **Mysql** I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have provided valid credentials and have installed latest mysqlclient. To install mysqlclient use command `pip install -I mysqlclient`.